# Simple shift cipher probability exercise

Tags: probability

This is a super simple probability exercise:
If we have a simple shift/ceasar cipher.

Let's say that there are only three messages encypted.

```
P ( M = kim) = 0.5

P (M = ann) = 0.2

P (M = boo) = 0.3
What is P(M = ann | C = DQQ)?
```

So if `C = DQQ` then I know that `M != kim`.

therefore:

```
P(M = ann | C = DQQ) = 0.4
```

So, I was wondering if this is the correct way of reasoning about this? If I can simply rule out some of the possible plaintexts, can I just bump up the probability of the remaining ones?

Comment: Yes, that is true. | means [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)  $$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$